# CodeceptJS - canvas manipulation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I am writing an E2E test for our application. On one page there is a canvas that is showing a PDF file. The test case is show this page, scroll to the bottom of the PDF and check if the button under the canvas is no longer disabled. Imagine a common licence agreements window in some application or software installation.

The problem is I have no idea how to scroll down in said canvas. It is not in iframe, so I cant switch into it. Functions provided by CodeceptJS scrolls only on the page and not on the canvas.

Has anyone did something familiar and know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
I.useWebDriverTo('scroll to bottom of the amendment canvas', async ({ browser }) => {
  const canvas = await browser.$('#amendment-preview > canvas')
  const button = await browser.$('button[data-qa="confirm-amendment-button"]')
  canvas.click()
  while (await button.getAttribute('disabled')) {
    await browser.keys('ArrowDown')
  }
})
```